# How to describe entries of an array in Javadoc

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, documentation, javadoc

If I have a matrix like this

```
int[][] people = {   { 20, 18, 22, 20, 16 },
                     { 18, 20, 18, 21, 20 },
                      { 16, 18, 16, 20, 24 },
                      {  25, 24, 22, 24, 25 }};
```

And I want to write in my Javadoc that each row represents a person and the first entry of a person represents his house number, the second his age,... Is there a standard way to do it? My try:

```
/**
 *Information about all people, every entry is an array about one person with:
 *index 0: house number
 *index 1: age
 ....
```

Comment: Is this int[][] publicly facing?  It shouldn't need a Javadoc if not.  If it is, is there a better design than int[][]?  Perhaps with a `Person` class and `Person[]` array (or list)?

Comment: If you are happy with how you're returning the data though, then the way you're handling the javadoc seems fine to me, but I would put it in the param or return section of the Javadoc (wherever this int[][] is applicable).

Comment: Kind of a weird question indeed.. The way you've commented seems alright and it's completely a matter of taste as long as it makes sense it's fine. I also agree with @Ironcache that intuitively, there might be better ways to design your "people" collection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd refactor the code as suggested in my comment (because Arrays are not meant to be treated as anything other than sequential data storage).  The associated javadoc (and code) would inherently look a lot more intuitive (to the point where it doesn't even really need the javadoc):

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    /** Their house number */
    public int houseNumber;

    /** Their age */
    public int age;

    ... // Other parameters and constructor.
        // also consider private members with getters/setters.
}
```

Main Code

```
/** A group of people. */
public Person[] people =
    { new Person(20, 18, 22, 20, 16),
      new Person(18, 20, 18, 21, 20),
      new Person(16, 18, 16, 20, 24),
      new Person(25, 24, 22, 24, 25)};
```

Otherwise, if you do not want to refactor, what you have is fine, but I'd look at the param and return parameters if it is accessed through a method (not a public variable):

```
/**
 * Description here.
 * 
 * @return Description of return type here
 * (IE: describe the indices in this section).
 */
public int[][] getPeople() {
    return new int[][]
            {{ 20, 18, 22, 20, 16 },
            { 18, 20, 18, 21, 20 },
            { 16, 18, 16, 20, 24 },
            {  25, 24, 22, 24, 25 }};
}

/**
 * Description here.
 * 
 * @param people Describe the "people" parameter here
 * (IE: describe the indices in this section).
 */
public void setPeople(int[][] people) {
    // Do whatever using the "2D" array.
}
```

These parameters are only really applicable if you're javadoc-ing a method though; if `int[][] people` is a public variable, then what you have is good enough.

Continuing on that train of thought, and as I eluded to in my comments, javadoc is meant to describe meaningful public parameters and methods to external (outside package) resources that would implement them.  If the methods/parameters are not public, then normal comments should be fine.

Really, all that matters is that you concisely and coherently get across the point of what is contained within your data.  If you feel like you've met that goal, and (*more importantly*) the people reading your javadoc agree, then I'd say you're okay.